# multiple value from dropdown in livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a dropdown and text input in a form. Form creates a course and I want to select classroom for course from dropdown and write its capacity to text input. But a course may have mutiple classrooms. How can I keep these classrooms and their capacity and show them in a table under the form?Like this:
[image]

Here's my code that keeps only one classroom and capacity

```php
<div class="sm:col-start-1 sm:col-end-3 col-span-3  ">
    <x-select x-on:change="isShowing = $event.target.value" name="classroom_id" label="{!! __('Classroom') !!}" wire:model="classroom_id"
            id="classroom_id"
            :options="$this->classrooms"/>
    <x-jet-input-error for="classroom_id" class="mt-2" />
</div>
<div class="col-span-2 sm:col-span-1 " x-show="isShowing">
    <label class="tf-form-label" for="capacity">
        {{ __('Capacity') }}
    </label>
    <input wire:model.debounce.250ms="capacity" type="text" name="capacity" id="capacity" class="tf-input" />
    <x-jet-input-error for="capacity" class="mt-2" />
</div>
```

```php
$this->form->save();// firstly course saved
$classroom = new Classroom();
$classroom->course_id = $this->form->id;
$classroom->classroom_id = $this->classroom_id;
$classroom->capacity = $this->capacity;
$classroom->save();
```

Comment: you should write the code for it, and if any issue please come here to help you to achieve your goals

Answer (score 1):

Add the following codes in your component.

**Component**

```
 public $classroom_id, $capacity;
 
 $course = Course::create($validatedCourseData); // firstly course saved
 
 // $this->classroom_id is array, because we set "multiple" in blade file
 $course->classrooms()->attach($this->classroom_id);
```

**Blade**

Please add multiple in in your select box code.

```
<div class="sm:col-start-1 sm:col-end-3 col-span-3  ">
    <x-select x-on:change="isShowing = $event.target.value" name="classroom_id" label="{!! __('Classroom') !!}" wire:model="classroom_id"
            id="classroom_id"
            :options="$this->classrooms" multiple/>
    <x-jet-input-error for="classroom_id" class="mt-2" />
</div>
<div class="col-span-2 sm:col-span-1 " x-show="isShowing">
    <label class="tf-form-label" for="capacity">
        {{ __('Capacity') }}
    </label>
    <input wire:model.debounce.250ms="capacity" type="text" name="capacity" id="capacity" class="tf-input" />
    <x-jet-input-error for="capacity" class="mt-2" />
</div>
```